# Veryfing pg_restore database with pg_dump database

Tags: migration, pg-dump, pg-restore

I just did a migration from Postgres 9.4 to 10 database.
How to verify if everything is okay?

I tried to look into huge tables, the rows are different (somehow in Postgres 10 then are more rows than in 9.4)

```
PSQL 9.4: 14 583 936 
PSQL 10:  14 880 545
```

here are my pg_dump and pg_restore commands which were executed without errors, but took very long process, dump was 12hours, while pg_restore 10hours:

```
pg_dump    -U postgres -d hive -Z1 -Fc -f /mnt/offline_backups/hive_full_2019-03-01_1630.dmp 2> /mnt/offline_backups/hive_full_2019-03-01_1630.log
pg_restore -U postgres -d hive -v         /mnt/offline_backups/hive_full_2019-03-01_1630.dmp
```

both commands were without errors whatsoever.

Here some screenshots from pgadmin 4v:
[image]

In both DB I just sorted rows count in descending order.

As you can see, rows inserted is quite different.

Here is summary:

[image]

Comment: Those numbers are only estimates. The only way to get the real row count is to run `select count(*)` on every table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to A_horse_with_no_name for a suggestion, i did some of the tables select count(*) and returned identical rows for each table.